# FixedThreadPool

Tags: java, eclipse, threadpool

What I need to do is use a **FixedThreadPool** of size 3 and then use it to print the ThreadName and then make it go to sleep for a random amount of time within a specified time interval and print that it is awake when it is done. I need to do it thread by thread but my output is coming with all the 3 threads together.

Desired output:
pool-1-thread-1 Going to sleep for random amount of time interval between 800 ms and 1000ms

pool-1-thread-1 done sleeping

pool-1-thread-2 Going to sleep for random amount of time interval between 800 ms and 1000ms

pool-1-thread-2 done sleeping

pool-1-thread-3 Going to sleep for random amount of time interval between 800 ms and 1000ms

pool-1-thread-3 done sleeping

I need to use FixedThreadPool only

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Sleep implements Runnable
{
 public void run()
  {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int randomnumber = ran.nextInt(1000-800+1)+800;
    System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ");
    System.out.println("Going to sleep for random amount of time interval between 800 ms and 1000ms");
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(randomnumber);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" done sleeping");
    Thread.yield();
 }
}

public class Ch6Ex3 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        exe.execute(new Sleep());
    }
    exe.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of multithreading when you need them to execute fully sequentially?

Comment: If you need to do it thread by thread - you should use `newSingleThreadExecutor` instead of pool with 3 threads.

Comment: give us example of desired and real output

Comment: Yielding before terminating is very inefficient. Don't do that.

Comment: Better update your question, this is not readable.

Comment: Why do you need pool with 3 threads. If you use 3-thread pool it means you can run up to 3 threads concurrently and that contradicts your goal.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I need to make 3 instances of the runnable implementation and execute it by using a FixedThreadPool.What should I do?

Comment: You can use FixedThreadPool with only 1 thread. Than only 1 instance of runnable will be invoked in any moment of time. Also check `newSingleThreadExecutor` method, I think it's what you need.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I know about newSingleThreadExecutor but I need to use newFixedThreadPool.

Comment: try `newFixedThreadPool(1)`

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I think I got it...I did what u asked and then I made 3 instances of the class and passed it to the thread pool one by one...:) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create thread pool with only 1 thread. If you use 3 threads then up to 3 runnable can be run concurrently and it's not what you want. So use:

```
ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Actually better option will be to use `newSingleThreadExecutor` because it explicitly shows that it runs only 1 runnable at any given time:

```
ExecutorService exe = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Internally both methods create `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 1 thread so there is no actual difference between them only in naming.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the objects immediately after one another (within the same ms), they'll probably have the same seed in their Random instances - therefore they'll sleep for the same amount of time.

From javadoc:

```
Creates a new random number generator. Its seed is initialized to a value based on the current time:
 public Random() { this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }
Two Random objects created within the same millisecond will have the same sequence of random numbers.
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this one. Is there another way to create different PRNGs within the same millisecond?

Comment: What Java version are you looking at? That's not how it works in newer versions. In newer versions, seeds are made unique even if created the same nano second.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that there's a problem in your code.

```
Thread.yield();
```

is redundant.

If you need that to execute one by one you don't need thread pool. You may just invoke `Sleep#run` from within your `for` loop creating different instances of `Sleep` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that to work using `FixedThreadPool` and you wanna exactly 3 separate threads done your work you should use Locks. Like this: First thread is locking your Lock on entrance and unlocking on exit. Next threads will wait for Lock to relase and do the same stuff.

Read more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html